# cannot run java app on mac properly

Tags: java, macos, bonjour, jar

I have small problem..I created a java App in windows and my .jar consist of whole app..i copied this jar file to mac and executed it from there it works fine..
 Java App consists of bonjour code if i execute .jar on windows it works fine and bonjour starts advertising...But,for mac the app runs fine but doesnot advertise the bonjourservice..
I am not understanding the difference..can anyone explain me y it is so?

Comment: Perhaps if something it not working there is a bug?  Try running app from command line with "java -jar' switch. See if any stack traces or other serious diagnostics are getting output. If the are, add them as a 'comment' to your question.  If you are catching exceptions and not logging them or rethrowing them, your program is going to be very hard to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

Because on the Mac the OS will do that for you, so you have to register it with the system service, rather than do the whole protocol yourself.  Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do that in Java.